# Hitting "Enter" on a form is not running JavaScript function and it's reloading the page. Why?

Tags: javascript

I created a form to run a JavaScript function to generate part numbers off of the input. The input can only be certain values, so there are errors that will show if the input is not a valid input.

The reset form button works, the submit button works, but only on click. I'd like to submit the form on Enter, and that's where I'm getting the issue. It runs the function but then refreshes (or resets, can't figure out which) the form.

I've looked at different options for submitting on Enter but it doesn't work unless I remove the form tags, which ends up breaking the primary purpose of the tool.

In the code, I shortened my library as it is quite long.

```
<script>
  var input = document.getElementById("deconstructSubmit");
  input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
      event.preventDefault();
      document.getElementById("deconstructSubmit").click();
    }
  });

  function resetForm() {
    document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
    document.getElementById("verify").classList.remove("is-invalid");
    document.getElementById("form-error-2").classList.add("hide");
    document.getElementById("form-error-1").classList.add("hide");
    document.getElementById("config").classList.add("hide");
    document.getElementById("STO").classList.add("hide");
    document.getElementById("warningHz").classList.add("hide");
    document.getElementById("warningMains").classList.add("hide");
  }

  function deconstructor() {
    var typeCode = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
    typeCode = typeCode.replace(/\s/g, '');
    typeCode = typeCode.toUpperCase();
    var library = ["I55AE125A10V01000S", "I55AE125A10V01001S", "I55AE125A10V01002S", "I55AE125A10V01003S"];

    if (library.indexOf(typeCode) === -1) {
      if (typeCode === "") {
        document.getElementById("verify").classList.add("is-invalid");
        document.getElementById("form-error-2").classList.add("hide");
        document.getElementById("form-error-1").classList.remove("hide");
        document.getElementById("config").classList.add("hide")
      } else {
        document.getElementById("form-error-1").classList.add("hide");
        document.getElementById("form-error-2").classList.remove("hide");
        document.getElementById("verify").classList.add("is-invalid");
        document.getElementById("config").classList.add("hide")
      }
    } else {
      document.getElementById("config").classList.remove("hide")
      document.getElementById("form-error-2").classList.add("hide");
      document.getElementById("form-error-1").classList.add("hide");
      document.getElementById("verify").classList.remove("is-invalid");


      /* Control Unit */
      var fieldBus = typeCode.substring(14, 17);
      switch (fieldBus) {
        case "000":
          fb = "0";
          io = "2"
          break;
        case "001":
          fb = "0";
          io = "3"
          break;
        case "002":
          fb = "C";
          io = "2"
          break;
        case "003":
          fb = "W";
          io = "2"
          break;
        case "00W":
          fb = "V";
          io = "2"
          break;
        case "004":
          fb = "P";
          io = "2"
          break;
        case "00K":
          fb = "T";
          io = "2"
          break;
        case "00L":
          fb = "R";
          io = "2"
          break;
        case "00M":
          fb = "G";
          io = "2"
          break;
        case "012":
          fb = "N";
          io = "2"
          break;
      }
      var controlUnit = 'I5CA5' + fb + '0' + io + '000VA1000S';
      document.getElementById("CUTC").innerHTML = controlUnit;

      /* Power Unit */
      var ratedPower = typeCode.substring(5, 8);
      var voltage = typeCode.substring(8, 9);
      var powerUnit = 'I5DAE' + typeCode.substring(5, 8) + typeCode.substring(8, 9) + '10V' + typeCode.substring(12, 13) + '0000S';
      document.getElementById("PUTC").innerHTML = powerUnit;

      /* STO */
      var safeTorque = typeCode.substring(10, 11);
      if (safeTorque === "A") {
        document.getElementById("STO").classList.remove("hide");
      } else {
        document.getElementById("STO").classList.add("hide");
      }

      /* Hz Check */
      if (typeCode.substring(13, 14) === "0") {
        document.getElementById("warningHz").classList.remove("hide");
      } else {
        document.getElementById("warningHz").classList.add("hide")
      }

      /* Mains Choke Check */
      var i = typeCode.substring(5, 8);
      i = parseInt(i);
      if (i >= 322) {
        document.getElementById("warningMains").classList.remove("hide");
      } else {
        document.getElementById("warningMains").classList.add("hide")
      };

    }
  };
</script>
<body>
  <div class="mainContainer doc-mainContainer">
    <div class="has-limited-width">
      <div class="grid-row">
        <div class="span-6 grid-columns">
          <div class="deconfig">
            <form id="myForm">
              <fieldset>
                <legend>i550 type code de-constructor tool</legend>
                <div id="verify" class="formField is-text is-mandatory">
                  <label class="formField-label" for="field-id">Enter type code</label>
                  <input class="formField-input" type="text" id="myInput" value="">
                  <span id="form-error-1" class="formField-message hide">Please enter type code</span>
                  <span id="form-error-2" class="formField-message hide">Invalid type code</span>
                  </div>
              </fieldset>
            </form>
            <button class="is-cta" id="deconstructSubmit" onclick="deconstructor()" type="submit">De-construct</button>
            <input class="is-cta" id="resetForm" type="reset" onclick="resetForm()" value="Reset form">
            <div class="deconfig hide" id="config">
              <h2>Type codes</h2>
              <table class="table">
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="row">
                      Control Unit:
                    </th>
                    <td>
                      <span id="CUTC"></span>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="row">
                      Power Unit:
                    </th>
                    <td>
                      <span id="PUTC"></span>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr id="STO" class="hide">
                    <th scope="row">
                      Safe Torque Off (STO):
                    </th>
                    <td>
                      I5MASV000000S
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
              <p class="hide red" id="warningHz">Please note that this is a 50Hz drive</p>
              <p class="hide red" id="warningMains">Inverters starting with 30 hp (22 kW) must always be used together with mains chokes.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

It should run the form and provide the correct output, whether it's submitting via click or enter.

Comment: Your submit button should be inside your form tags.

Comment: When I do that it breaks the tool. It runs the function and displays the results for a split second and then resets the form.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the issue by adding `action="#"` to the form tag.